# Query to collapse messages

Tags: mysql, database

```
id  job_id  sender_buyer rcpt_driver sender_driver rcpt_buyer action   text
100 10      0            0           34            55         message fhudos
101 10      0            0           34            55         message jgfjgf
102 10      55           34          0             0          post_job 
103 17      0            0           34            55         message gyujkf
104 17      55           34          0             0          message tgfdfd
```

I have a table that records all actions between users. Users come in 2 types: buyer and driver. Buyers only ever interact with drivers and vice versa.

The 'action' table records the type of action, and also the sender id and the rcpt id. Examples of actions are 'message', 'post_job', 'post_review' etc. For example the buyer might post a job, so an action goes in the 'action' table saying who was sender and who was rcpt of the action. Here is a sample of data from the table.

I want to do a query that the buyer would perform, the query will get his "actions", but not all of them. Just a subset for the "action" feed screen inside the app.

I want to select as follows:

1. get all actions, except messages, that the buyer sent (sender_buyer)
2. get all actions the buyer received (rcpt_buyer) but eliminate consecutive messages if they are from the same driver and for the same job (not easy)

The main purpose as you will hopefully see is to 'collapse' messages that appear in the feed if they are consecutively part of the same job and from the same driver. So if the driver sends the buyer 3 messages 1 after another, with no other actions occurring inbetween (chronologically), then these 3 messages are collapsed, i.e only the most recent is displayed. And then the next action and so forth, and each time a series of message actions occurs that are from the same driver for the same job, it eliminates the unwanted messages.

So in the table above we would get results:

```
100 <-- ELIMINATED - because job_id and sender_driver are same as the next action, which is more recent, so we hide this one
101 <-- SELECTED   - a message from a driver
102 <-- SELECTED   - Buyer posted a job
103 <-- SELECTED   - a message from a driver
104 <-- ELIMINATED - messages the buyer sent are not shown.
```

I dont want to start querying and then filtering them out in some loop because then I will have to do multiple queries to get a constant number of results back to the client app. I need everything in 1 query if possible so that I can paginate using LIMIT and OFFSET by simply passing the page number to my script.

Is it possible to do this in 1 query?

**UPDATE*
I think I need to do a join, where I join the next row that matches the same job_id and sender_driver and the id is greater than the current id. I can then ommit the row in the outser WHERE clause in order to filter out successive messages. Here is the query I have, its not complete yet:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM action as a1 
  INNER 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM action 
        ORDER 
           BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 1
     ) AS a2 
    ON a2.job_id = a1.job_id 
   AND a2.sender_driver = a1.sender_driver 
   AND a2.id > a1.id 
 WHERE (a1.sender_buyer = 52 AND a1.the_action <> 'message') 
    OR (a1.rcpt_buyer = 52 AND a2.the_action <> 'message');
```

The query runs but returns no results.

Comment: $actions is not mysql syntax

Comment: its called a variable, im using ORM

Comment: Not according to your tags you're not. My point really was none of that stuff is mysql, so there's not much point tagging it as such

Comment: Ok i will update the tags. I have actually made some progress, i think, please check my quesiton I added some more info

Comment: Well, it's certainly getting better. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i wish i knew how to express the problem better, theres so many tables though and doing create statements for everything would add lots of irrelevant info. I thought i had made it clear but it seems I am lacking in details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170417/discussion-between-brux-and-strawberry).

Comment: I feel like I've explained how